# Search optimization using Apache Lucene

Tags: java, hadoop, lucene, cloudera

I am working on a project to implement large scale indexing on twitter data for search optimization using Apache Lucene. Lucene provides inverted index to filter out the blocks which match the specified selection criteria.

To implement this project, how should I go about it - Should I install the Cloudera vm and proceed? or Should I deploy Hadoop from Apache on Ubuntu platform?

The reason I am asking this is because I am not able to confirm if Cloudera already uses Lucene to optimize search.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera gives you debian packages and software for automatic installation and cluster management. That's it. There is nothing about search (and it's optimization) in Hadoop stack. So you may choose either vanilla or cloudera for you project.

For search you can use Elasticsearch. It have [integration with hadoop](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/hadoop/) and uses Lucene internally